# On the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n \geq 0} \frac{x_{n}}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\left\lbrace x_{n} \right\rbrace _{n \geq 0}$ be a sequence which converges to $0$. Is the series $\sum\limits_{n \geq 0} \dfrac{x_{n}}{n}$ convergent or not?

In fact the question is for which $p \in \mathbb{R}$, $\sum\limits_{n \geq 0} \dfrac{x_{n}}{n^{p}}$ converges? I can show that when $p>1$ then it converges since $\sum\limits_{n \geq 0} \dfrac{1}{n^{p}} < + \infty$ and for $p<1$ I have some counter-examples. But I'm not sure about the case $p=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just take $x_n = \frac{1}{\log(n)}$ ! By Bertrand's theorem for series :

$$ \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k \log(k)} = \infty $$

Comment: What's "Bertrand's theorem"? I recognize this divergent series, but I've never heard of that name outside of results on primes.

Comment: I'm really sorry. The series of $\frac{1}{n^{\alpha}\log(n)^{\beta}}$ are called "Bertrand's series" in France, I did not know that it was not the case elsewhere !

Comment: but I guess you can also prove this using Integral test, for example

Comment: Yes the idea is to compare the sum to an integral !